# Upload multiple featured images in a custom post (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, image, custom-post-type

I have a custom post and I would like to upload many featured images.  I know there are some plugins doing that but I would like to try it without installing a plugin. Is it possible? 
Any help/opinion is appreciated

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, there is only ONE featured image. But you could create a custom meta box where you could add new images. Here's an example using the wordpress uploader:

**functions.php** or **my-plugin.php**:

```
//init the meta box
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_postimage_setup' );
function custom_postimage_setup(){
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_postimage_meta_box' );
    add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_postimage_meta_box_save' );
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box(){

    //on which post types should the box appear?
    $post_types = array('post','page');
    foreach($post_types as $pt){
        add_meta_box('custom_postimage_meta_box',__( 'More Featured Images', 'yourdomain'),'custom_postimage_meta_box_func',$pt,'side','low');
    }
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post){

    //an array with all the images (ba meta key). The same array has to be in custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post_id) as well.
    $meta_keys = array('second_featured_image','third_featured_image');

    foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key){
        $image_meta_val=get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true);
        ?>
        <div class="custom_postimage_wrapper" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>_wrapper" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <img src="<?php echo ($image_meta_val!=''?wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_meta_val)[0]:''); ?>" style="width:100%;display: <?php echo ($image_meta_val!=''?'block':'none'); ?>" alt="">
            <a class="addimage button" onclick="custom_postimage_add_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('add image','yourdomain'); ?></a><br>
            <a class="removeimage" style="color:#a00;cursor:pointer;display: <?php echo ($image_meta_val!=''?'block':'none'); ?>" onclick="custom_postimage_remove_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('remove image','yourdomain'); ?></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" value="<?php echo $image_meta_val; ?>" />
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <script>
    function custom_postimage_add_image(key){

        var $wrapper = jQuery('#'+key+'_wrapper');

        custom_postimage_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: '<?php _e('select image','yourdomain'); ?>',
            button: {
                text: '<?php _e('select image','yourdomain'); ?>'
            },
            multiple: false
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.on('select', function() {

            var attachment = custom_postimage_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            var img_url = attachment['url'];
            var img_id = attachment['id'];
            $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val(img_id);
            $wrapper.find('img').attr('src',img_url);
            $wrapper.find('img').show();
            $wrapper.find('a.removeimage').show();
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.on('open', function(){
            var selection = custom_postimage_uploader.state().get('selection');
            var selected = $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val();
            if(selected){
                selection.add(wp.media.attachment(selected));
            }
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.open();
        return false;
    }

    function custom_postimage_remove_image(key){
        var $wrapper = jQuery('#'+key+'_wrapper');
        $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val('');
        $wrapper.find('img').hide();
        $wrapper.find('a.removeimage').hide();
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    wp_nonce_field( 'custom_postimage_meta_box', 'custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce' );
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post_id){

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts', $post_id ) ){ return 'not permitted'; }

    if (isset( $_POST['custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce'],'custom_postimage_meta_box' )){

        //same array as in custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post)
        $meta_keys = array('second_featured_image','third_featured_image');
        foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key){
            if(isset($_POST[$meta_key]) && intval($_POST[$meta_key])!=''){
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, intval($_POST[$meta_key]));
            }else{
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To create more images you can adjust the`$meta_keys`-Array in `custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post)`and `custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post)`

To get the saved image ID, you can use `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'second_featured_image', true);`. So maybe like this:

`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'second_featured_image', true),'thumbnail'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks a lot Nico that really worked. To get the saved image I used :    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'second_featured_image', true),'full'); ?>

Comment: Works perfectly! I did change the $post_id to get_the_ID() in order to get the images. Thank you for the code

Comment: Another solution: create custom image (or any file) fields for posts using ACF, and get other powerful possibilities too.

Comment: Excellent. This worked without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nico Martin wrote a great answer!

I found a few things that, in my opinion, could be improved for a better user experience.

The button and preview styles needed to be adjusted in order to stay consistent with the existing WordPress admin styles, so I added the proper wp classes accordingly. This way any updates to the WordPress admin, and admin themes will work properly.

I added aria text to improve accessibility compatibility.

The original code returned the thumbnail size, which was showing blurry images and cropped images in the preview. I've updated the code to return the 'large' size, and made it visually simpler to use any size you prefer by changing the second parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_meta_val , 'large')`.

I added an hr element to provide better visual separation between the images.

I adjusted to text to reflect the current featured-image button text.

I changed the js and PHP to better hide/show the containers and buttons.

I added more images, as I needed them for my project. These can easily be adjusted by adding more names to or removing names from the $meta_array. Remember that any changes made to this value need to be made in both places the variable occurs.

This should provide a more consistent flow visually and a better user experience all around.

**functions.php or my-plugin.php:**

```
<?php
//init the meta box
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_postimage_setup' );

function custom_postimage_setup(){
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_postimage_meta_box' );
    add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_postimage_meta_box_save' );
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box(){

    //on which post types should the box appear?
    $post_types = array('post','page','th-templates');
    foreach($post_types as $pt){
        add_meta_box('custom_postimage_meta_box',__( 'More Featured Images', 'yourdomain'),'custom_postimage_meta_box_func',$pt,'side','low');
    }
}


function custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post){

    //an array with all the images (ba meta key). The same array has to be in custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post_id) as well.
    $meta_keys = array('featured_image_2','featured_image_3','featured_image_4','featured_image_5','featured_image_6', 'featured_image_7');

    foreach($meta_keys as $index => $meta_key){
        $image_meta_val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true);
        $image_array = $image_meta_val ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_meta_val , 'large') : '';
        ?>
        <div class="custom_postimage_wrapper" style="margin-bottom:20px;" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>_container">

            <div class="editor-post-featured-image__container" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>_wrapper" style="display:<?php echo ($image_meta_val?'block':'none'); ?>;">

                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" value="<?php echo $image_meta_val; ?>" />

                <button type="button" onclick="custom_postimage_add_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');" aria-label="Edit or update the image" aria-describedby="editor-post-featured-image-11-describedby" class="components-button editor-post-featured-image__preview">
                    <div class="components-responsive-wrapper">
                        <span id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>_padding" ></span>
                        <img id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>_img" src="<?php echo $image_array?$image_array[0]:''; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_array?$image_array[1]:''; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_array?$image_array[2]:''; ?>" alt="" class="components-responsive-wrapper__content" data-meta_image_id="<?php echo $image_array?$meta_key:0; ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </button>

                <button type="button" style="margin-top:1em; display:block;" class="replaceimage components-button is-secondary" onclick="custom_postimage_add_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('Replace Image ' .$index+2,'waas-hero'); ?></button>

                <button type="button" class="removeimage components-button is-link is-destructive" style="margin-top:1em; display:block;" onclick="custom_postimage_remove_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('Remove featured image '.$index+2,'yourdomain'); ?></button>

            </div>

            <button type="button" style="display:<?php echo ($image_meta_val?'none':'block'); ?>;" class="addimage components-button is-secondary" onclick="custom_postimage_add_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('Add Image ' .$index+2,'waas-hero'); ?></button>


        </div>
        <hr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;" />
    <?php } ?>
    <script>

    window.onload = function() {
        var images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-meta_image_id]');
        images.forEach(setImgPadding);

        //adjust padding wrapper
        function setImgPadding(img) {
            var meta_id = img.dataset.meta_image_id
            if(meta_id == 0) return;
            jQuery('#'+meta_id+'_padding').css('height', img.scrollHeight);
        }
    }

    function custom_postimage_add_image(key){

        var $wrapper = jQuery('#'+key+'_wrapper');

        custom_postimage_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: '<?php _e('select image','yourdomain'); ?>',
            button: {
                text: '<?php _e('select image','yourdomain'); ?>'
            },
            multiple: false
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.on('select', function() {

            var attachment = custom_postimage_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            //set input with new img id
            $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val(attachment['id']);


            //remove old image and old height property
            var pad = document.getElementById(key+'_padding').style.removeProperty('height');
            $wrapper.find('img').remove();

            //create new image
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.id = attachment['id']+'_img';
            img.src = attachment['url'];
            img.width = attachment['width'];
            img.height = attachment['height'];
            img.dataset.meta_image_id = key;

            document.getElementById(key+'_padding').appendChild(img)

            $wrapper.show();

            var $container = jQuery('#'+key+'_container');
            $container.find('button.addimage').hide();

        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.on('open', function(){
            var selection = custom_postimage_uploader.state().get('selection');
            var selected = $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val();
            if(selected){
                selection.add(wp.media.attachment(selected));
            }
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.open();
        return false;
    }

    function custom_postimage_remove_image(key){
        var $wrapper = jQuery('#'+key+'_wrapper');
        $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val('');
        $wrapper.hide();
        var $container = jQuery('#'+key+'_container');
        $container.find('button.addimage').show();
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    wp_nonce_field( 'custom_postimage_meta_box', 'custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce' );
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post_id){

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts', $post_id ) ){ return 'not permitted'; }

    if (isset( $_POST['custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce'],'custom_postimage_meta_box' )){
        //same array as in custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post)
        $meta_keys = array('featured_image_2','featured_image_3','featured_image_4','featured_image_5','featured_image_6', 'featured_image_7');
        foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key){
            if(isset($_POST[$meta_key]) && intval($_POST[$meta_key])!=''){
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, intval($_POST[$meta_key]));
            }else{
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get the saved image URL, height, and width, and display the image in your theme, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$img_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured_image_2', true);
$image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id , 'large'); 
$img_url = $image_array[0];
$img_width = $image_array[1];
$img_height = $image_array[2];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" width="<?php echo $img_width ?>" height="<?php echo $img_height; ?>" />
```

Replace the second parameter of `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured_image_2', true)` with any of the names that you used in the $meta_array to get that image.