# How to add multiple featured image upload button without plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add 2nd featured image upload button without using plugin for wordpress?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to **add multi-post-thumbnails-admin.js**  also you need to add filters for the same for details Refer below link  - http://lifeonlars.com/wordpress/how-to-add-multiple-featured-images-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you. It’s exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @gulhan  Welcome :)

Comment: OP: "Without a plugin", accepted answer: "Use this plugin"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506088/upload-multiple-featured-images-in-a-custom-post-wordpress >> this is a much better answer.