# How to add multiple featured images without a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

This [other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510277/how-to-add-multiple-featured-image-upload-button-without-plugin-for-wordpress) is exactly what I need, but the answer on it is a [link](http://lifeonlars.com/wordpress/how-to-add-multiple-featured-images-in-wordpress/) that is 5+ years outdated.

It tells me to change the following code:

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script("featured-image-custom", plugins_url(basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/js/multi-post-thumbnails-admin.js'), array('jquery'));
}
```

to this:

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts() {
    $template_url = get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/multi-post-thumbnails-admin.js';
    wp_enqueue_script("featured-image-custom",  $template_url, array('jquery'));
}
```

but the updated plugin now has this instead:

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
    global $wp_version, $post_ID;

    // only load on select pages
    if ( ! in_array( $hook, array( 'post-new.php', 'post.php', 'media-upload-popup' ) ) )
        return;

    if (version_compare($wp_version, '3.5', '<')) { 
        add_thickbox();
        wp_enqueue_script( "mpt-featured-image", $this->plugins_url( 'js/multi-post-thumbnails-admin.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'media-upload' ) );
    } else { // 3.5+ media modal
        wp_enqueue_media( array( 'post' => ( $post_ID ? $post_ID : null ) ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( "mpt-featured-image", $this->plugins_url( 'js/multi-post-thumbnails-admin.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'set-post-thumbnail' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( "mpt-featured-image-modal", $this->plugins_url( 'js/media-modal.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'media-models' ) );                
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( "mpt-admin-css", $this->plugins_url( 'css/multi-post-thumbnails-admin.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
```

I've tried leaving it as is, changing all of them like the blog link says, and adding the $template_url variable every time is says $this. In the back end of WordPress, I see the 2nd featured image, but the only thing it does is add a number sign (#) to the editor's url.

Here's also my code added to the functions.php file:

```
// Load external file to add support for MultiPostThumbnails. Allows you to set more than one "feature image" per post.
require_once('library/multi-post-thumbnails.php');

// Define additional "post thumbnails". Relies on MultiPostThumbnails to work
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
        'label' => '2nd Feature Image',
        'id' => 'feature-image-2',
        'post_type' => 'page'
        )
    );
    new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
        'label' => '3rd Feature Image',
        'id' => 'feature-image-3',
        'post_type' => 'home'
        )
    );
};
```

Please and thank you for your time.

Comment: What version of WP are you using? Have you reviewed the following: https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/issues/ & https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/multiple-post-thumbnails ?

Comment: I'm using version 4.5.3 of WordPress, and no I haven't stumbled onto those links yet. I will look at them now.

Comment: It seems others might be having issues with this plugin in 4.5.3

Comment: In the github link, the one that is titled "Doesn t work on wp 4.5.3" is having a different issue. The one title something similar links to that page. It possible that it's still the WP update, but I'm not entirely sure since it's not the same issue. Any advice?

Comment: Are you able to show any errors? Have you tried disabling other plugins etc? Have you tried this on a separate installation of WP? You're basically at a point of troubleshooting and more troubleshooting.

Comment: No errors are coming through the console, and I've disabled all of the plugins. I installed the MultiPost Thumbnails plugin to see if it was the plugin or the files, and the plugin works fine. However, I would rather not use the plugin if I can manage to do so.

Comment: What reason do you wish to not use the plugin?

Comment: I try to make it a practice not to use plugins if I can manage. Between security reasons, limitation of excess code, and wanting to know how everything works, I feel it's a better product for the client at the end.

Comment: I understand your logic, but from experience you can probably rest easy using a plugin. If it doesn't meet your needs in terms of security or markup, I'm sure the license will allow you to make modifications. ** I am very picky myself about plugins and often modify third-party plugins or merge them with one I wrote as a "master" plugin for my network.

Comment: So how are you writing this into the site? Theme functions.php?

Comment: A child theme's functions.php, and editing the multi-post-thumbnails.php in a library folder inside the child theme as directed by the tutorial.

Comment: That's your problem. It won't work in your themes functions file as written. It wasn't intended to. It's ok to use a plugin, man. It doesn't compromise the project or integrity of your work. Just be sure to test the plugin and check for security issues. Don't over complicate it. Cheers.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, but my question is about not using a plugin. I will see if anyone else can help. Thank you for your time.