# Multiple Images/ Slider with custom post [single.php]

Tags: wordpress, customization

I am looking for a approach to add multiple images option under the Feature image section in wordPress custom post type. I will integrate/implement these images on `single.php` file where I want to show the slider images. I want to do it using `Codex / coding` approach, Please NO PLUGIN. Any Idea/help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have found this code and it has to be pasted in `function.php or plugin.php`. I have create a new file `plug-slider.php` and add the below code there & its not working, but the issue is that I have to call each image separately instead like create an array and call the array, also if there is no second/third image set for other post then the slider block is showing empty.. I don't know why, may be I am missing something... can someone please review.

Code Reference: [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506088/upload-multiple-featured-images-in-a-custom-post-wordpress)

```
//init the meta box
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_postimage_setup' );
function custom_postimage_setup(){
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_postimage_meta_box' );
    add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_postimage_meta_box_save' );
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box(){

    //on which post types should the box appear?
    $post_types = array('portfolios','page');
    foreach($post_types as $pt){
        add_meta_box('custom_postimage_meta_box',__( 'More Featured Images', 'yourdomain'),'custom_postimage_meta_box_func',$pt,'side','low');
    }
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post){

    //an array with all the images (ba meta key). The same array has to be in custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post_id) as well.
    $meta_keys = array('second_featured_image','third_featured_image');

    foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key){
        $image_meta_val=get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true);
        ?>
        <div class="custom_postimage_wrapper" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>_wrapper" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <img src="<?php echo ($image_meta_val!=''?wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_meta_val)[0]:''); ?>" style="width:100%;display: <?php echo ($image_meta_val!=''?'block':'none'); ?>" alt="">
            <a class="addimage button" onclick="custom_postimage_add_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('add image','yourdomain'); ?></a><br>
            <a class="removeimage" style="color:#a00;cursor:pointer;display: <?php echo ($image_meta_val!=''?'block':'none'); ?>" onclick="custom_postimage_remove_image('<?php echo $meta_key; ?>');"><?php _e('remove image','yourdomain'); ?></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" id="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" value="<?php echo $image_meta_val; ?>" />
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <script>
    function custom_postimage_add_image(key){

        var $wrapper = jQuery('#'+key+'_wrapper');

        custom_postimage_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: '<?php _e('select image','yourdomain'); ?>',
            button: {
                text: '<?php _e('select image','yourdomain'); ?>'
            },
            multiple: false
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.on('select', function() {

            var attachment = custom_postimage_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            var img_url = attachment['url'];
            var img_id = attachment['id'];
            $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val(img_id);
            $wrapper.find('img').attr('src',img_url);
            $wrapper.find('img').show();
            $wrapper.find('a.removeimage').show();
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.on('open', function(){
            var selection = custom_postimage_uploader.state().get('selection');
            var selected = $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val();
            if(selected){
                selection.add(wp.media.attachment(selected));
            }
        });
        custom_postimage_uploader.open();
        return false;
    }

    function custom_postimage_remove_image(key){
        var $wrapper = jQuery('#'+key+'_wrapper');
        $wrapper.find('input#'+key).val('');
        $wrapper.find('img').hide();
        $wrapper.find('a.removeimage').hide();
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    wp_nonce_field( 'custom_postimage_meta_box', 'custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce' );
}

function custom_postimage_meta_box_save($post_id){

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts', $post_id ) ){ return 'not permitted'; }

    if (isset( $_POST['custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_postimage_meta_box_nonce'],'custom_postimage_meta_box' )){

        //same array as in custom_postimage_meta_box_func($post)
        $meta_keys = array('second_featured_image','third_featured_image');
        foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key){
            if(isset($_POST[$meta_key]) && intval($_POST[$meta_key])!=''){
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, intval($_POST[$meta_key]));
            }else{
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> My Callback code in single.php

```
<div class="project-carousel owl-carousel js-project-carousel">
  <?php
                   
                   while(have_posts()) {
                       the_post(); ?>
    <!-- <div class="project-detail-item">
    <?php //the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-slider') ?>
    </div> -->
    
    <?php 
    $slider_img=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'second_featured_image', true),'full');
    if($slider_img !='')
                   {?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
                  <?php
          echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'second_featured_image', true),'full');
                   ?>
                </div>   
                  <?php }
                   else
                   {
                    the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-slider');
                   }
    ?>
    
  </div>
```

again the `if/else` block works for the empty check but only for single instance, like I have to check for each image... or I messed up?

Comment: Please check this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/custom-gallery-metabox.html I think it will help you

Comment: @Mo'menMohamed  can you please review the EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the below change and then try...

in your plugin file change this line.

`$meta_keys = array('second_featured_image','third_featured_image');`

To
 `$meta_keys = array('second_featured_image','third_featured_image','fourth_featured_image','fifth_featured_image');`

change your call back `single.php` file code to something like below. Loop through each file and check for empty.
I have modified the code to accept up to 5/6 images so you can use it in the slider.

```
<div class="project-carousel owl-carousel js-project-carousel">
  <?php
                   
                   while(have_posts()) {
                       the_post();
    $slider_img=the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-slider');
    $slider_img1=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'second_featured_image', true),'full');
    $slider_img2=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'third_featured_image', true),'full');
    $slider_img3=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'fourth_featured_image', true),'full');
    $slider_img4=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'fifth_featured_image', true),'full');
    $slider_img5=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'six_featured_image', true),'full');
    $slider_img6=wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'svn_featured_image', true),'full');
    if($slider_img !='')
                   {?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
                  <?php echo $slider_img;?>
                   </div> 
                   <?php }?>
                   <?php if($slider_img1 !=''){ ?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
               <?php echo $slider_img1; ?>
                </div>  
                <?php }?> 
                <?php if($slider_img2 !=''){ ?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
               <?php echo $slider_img2; ?>
                </div>  
                <?php }?> 
                <!--image-->
                <?php if($slider_img3 !=''){ ?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
               <?php echo $slider_img3; ?>
                </div>  
                <?php }?> 

                <!--image end-->
                <!--image-->
                <?php if($slider_img4 !=''){ ?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
               <?php echo $slider_img4; ?>
                </div>  
                <?php }?> 
                <!--image end-->
                <!--image-->
                <?php if($slider_img5 !=''){ ?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
               <?php echo $slider_img5; ?>
                </div>  
                <?php }?> 
                <!--image end-->
                <!--image-->
                <?php if($slider_img6 !=''){ ?>
                    <div class="project-detail-item">
               <?php echo $slider_img6; ?>
                </div>  
                <?php }?> 
                <!--image end-->
                
    
  </div>
```